# Android Facebook error:invalid key hash. the key hash does not match any stored key hashes

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-3.1

I signed a new version for my app today.
I added facebook login to it.
When I tried it before uploading it to google play it showed me:
invalid key hash. the key hash does not match any stored key hashes
I'm using this command to create the hash to enter to facebook:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias XXXX-keystore "XXXX" | "C:\Dev\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\openssl.exe" sha1 -binary | "C:\Dev\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\openssl.exe" base64
```

I checked that I use the same keystore and key that I use when I sign the app.
It worked for me with the development but not the production.
Do you have any idea?
I can't change the key for the app.

Answer (score 0):

May be it couldbe late to answer, I just searched 3 days ago to find solution for this.

Please use CORRECT your alias and the password of your alias when create it.

In my case password default  "android" still work even you had create another password for keystore : "123456" (this is working) , 2 passwords will have 2 different key hash, and only one working.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of this versions: openssl-0.9.8e _X64.zip

You should **not** use the openssl-0.9.8k_X64.zip.

difference is **k** and **e**

and generate key again using`keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64 on cmd`

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. run this command in terminal:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

Step 2. Enter password: "android"

See also:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/advanced